# Custom Context Menu bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created this context menu in react. Given an x and y coordinates by the mouse click event I assign them to the divs containing the context menu and a lateral submenu for bookmarks. The problem is that the menu options are clickable in any part of the div container, but the bookmark div doesn't allow me to click some bookmarks in some random area inside the same div container. I haven't been able to see what the problem is if they are both absolute. Is the problem somehow related to the propagation? Here's the code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

import { Space_Grotesk } from "@next/font/google";

const space_grotesk = Space_Grotesk({
    weight: "400",
    style: ["normal"],
    subsets: ["latin"],
});

type ContextMenuProps = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    closeContextMenu: () => void;
}

const ContextMenu: React.FC<ContextMenuProps> = ({ x, y, closeContextMenu }) => {
    const contextMenuRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
    const [openBookmark, setOpenBookmark] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMouseDown = (e: MouseEvent): void => {

          if (
            contextMenuRef.current &&
            !contextMenuRef.current.contains(e.target as Node)
          ) {
            setOpen(false);
            setOpenBookmark(false);
          }
        };
    
        const handleContextMenu = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
            const fileGallery = document.querySelector(".file-gallery-container");
          if (!open && fileGallery && fileGallery.contains(e.target as Node)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setOpen(true);
          }
        };
    
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextMenu);
    
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
          document.removeEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextMenu);
        };
      }, [open]);

    

    return (
        <div ref={contextMenuRef}>
            <div
            className={`absolute z-20 w-[178px] 
            bg-[#EEEEEE] rounded-[10px] [&>a]:flex
            [&>a]:h-[31px] [&>a]:flex-wrap [&>a]:items-center
            [&>a]:pl-3 [&>a]:text-[12px] 
            ${space_grotesk.className} ${open ? 'h-[238px]' : 'h-0'} 
            duration-300 transition-[height] overflow-hidden`} 
            style={{ top: `${y}px`, left: `${x}px` }}>
                <a className="mt-2 hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]">Cambiar Nombre</a>
                <a className="hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]">Agregar a favoritos</a>
                <a className="hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]">Cambiar de folder</a>
                <a className="hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]">Compartir</a>
                <a className="hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]">Copiar vinculo</a>
                <a className="hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]" onClick={()=>{setOpenBookmark((prevState) => !prevState)}}>Bookmark</a>
                <a className="mb-2 hover:bg-[#D9D9D9]">Mover a papelera</a>
            </div>
            <div
            className={`bookmark-container absolute w-[178px] ${openBookmark ? 'h-[178px]' : 'h-0'}
            bg-white shadow-custom rounded-[10px] duration-300 overflow-hidden`}
            style={{ top: `${y+(238-178)}px`, left: `${x+178+10}px` }}>
                
                <div className="flex flex-wrap m-3 gap-x-1 gap-y-4 [&>a]:inline-flex 
                [&>a]:justify-center [&>a]:items-center
                [&>a]:w-[35px]">
                    
                    {Array(12).fill(null).map((_, index) => (
                        <a className="h-[36px] hover:bg-[#EEEEEE] 
                        hover:duration-100 duration-100 rounded-[3px]" 
                        href='#' >
                            <div className="w-0 h-0 
                            border-t-[10px] border-t-solid border-t-blue
                            border-r-[10px] border-t-solid border-t-blue
                            border-b-[20px] border-t-solid border-t-transparent
                            border-l-[10px] border-t-solid border-t-blue rotate-180"></div>
                        </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default ContextMenu;
```